Failed GUI tests screenshots of assertj-swing-junit not uploading as GitHub Actions artifact
I'm having trouble setting up the assertj-swing-junit plugin (version 3.17.1) to upload screenshots of failed GUI tests as an artifact to GitHub Actions:
Warning: No files were found with the provided path: **/failed-gui-tests. No artifacts will be uploaded.

The problem encountered seems to be that the failed-gui-tests folder does not contain any files, even though the build log clearly states that the file was correctly inserted at test failing:
org.assertj.swing.junit.runner.FailureScreenshotTaker saveScreenshot
INFO: Screenshot of the failed test saved as '/home/runner/work/HelloWorld/failed-gui-tests/com.examples.helloworld.view.swing.HelloWorldSwingIT.testError.png

The dependency on Maven was set like this:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>.
  <artifactId>assertj-swing-junit</artifactId>.
  <version>3.17.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Instead, the workflow is defined like this:
name: Java CI with Maven in Linux
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      workdir: ${{ github.workspace }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
          - java: 8
    name: Build with Java ${{ matrix.java }} on Linux
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up JDK ${{ matrix.java }}
      uses: actions/setup-java@v4
      with:
        java-version: ${{ matrix.java }}
        distribution: 'temurin'
    - name: Cache Maven packages
      uses: actions/cache@v4
      with:
        path: ~/.m2
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml', '**/*.yml') }}
        restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: xvfb-run mvn clean verify
      working-directory: ${{ env.workdir }}
    - name: Generate JUnit Report
      run: mvn surefire-report:report-only site:site -DgenerateReports=false
      if: ${{ always() }}
    - name: Archive JUnit Report
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      if: ${{ always() }}
      with:
        name: surefire-report-jdk-${{ matrix.java }}
        path: '**/target/site'
    - name: Upload Screenshots
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      if: ${{ failure() }}
      with:
        name: failed-gui-tests-jdk-${{ matrix.java }}
        path: '**/failed-gui-tests'

Obviously the failed-gui-tests folder was excluded with .gitignore so as not to push tests to the repository by mistake. However, this should not be the problem (I tried removing it from the .gitignore file and the problem persists).
